# Programmin language of Windows Phone 7 OS

Tags: windows-phone-7

I was wondering what is Windows Phone 7 SDK language to write apps for this OS? And where can I download the SDK, is there any Mac version?

Comment: Why was this question voted down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use C# and the Silverlight framework for the Windows Phone 7. Get the [SDK here](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started). There are no Mac version of the tools.

Answer (score 5):

You can develop apps in C#, VB.NET, F# or IronRuby.

You can get all the tools and the SDK from http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started.

There is no Mac support for development. Apparently Windows runs well on Mac hardware though ;)

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering what is Windows Phone 7 SDK LNG to write apps for this OS. And where can I download the SDK

LNG stands for the programing language? [Go to App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-US) and you can download for free everthing you need to bulid apps. Basically, you can use C# or VB.Net (best support has C#), but there is possible to write some code in other language that run within .NET CF like F#, and there will be some support for native languages in the future.

> is there any Mac version

Nope, and I think we won't see it in the near future (if ever).